What flex connector size fits a HWT plate opening that’s 1-5/16” ID?
This is as about a specific as it gets.
The whip I bought is 1/2” and plenty big for the 10-2 wire but the connector is far too small.



You need to get a reducer bushing plate.
Use a bushing on each side of the plate. Tightened on the conduit, it will hold firmly.
A number of sizes are available to properly fit your application. These are used when an oversize knockout must be dealt with.

Great! I've used bushings like this when entering panels. Didn't know that was acceptable in this case. Thanks for your help.
